# How do I match daily level date data to hourly level date data in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

[Matching Daily to Hourly Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPnRA.png)

I am trying to match daily data to hourly data. If the data in column B matches column A regardless of the hour (0-23), it should input the value for daily data in column B to hourly data. I am not able to do this now because the dates are not exactly the same since the hourly data has the hour stamp, while the daily data is just DD/MM/YYYY. How can I match this?

Answer (score 0):

If cell `A1` has a date and time in it while `B1 has only the date in it, you can compare them by using

```
=IF(FLOOR.MATH(VALUE(A1),1)=VALUE(B1),"Same date","Different date")
```

In your case, if the formatting is unusual (like `DD/MM/YYYY HH` shown) and you don't care about the hour, you could simply ignore it

```
=IF((VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))=VALUE(B1),"Same date","Different date")
```

It would be useful to know the formatting of the A column though.

Answer (score 0):

The following formulas support "date as text" or "date as date" format in the column A (in red : text format).
If your dates in column B are formatted as text use :

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(ISTEXT(E4)=TRUE,LEFT(E4,10),TEXT(E4,"jj/mm/aaaa")),$H$3:$I$5,2,FALSE)
```

If your dates in column B are formatted as date use :

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(E13)=TRUE,DATE(YEAR(E13),MONTH(E13),DAY(E13)),DATEVALUE(LEFT(E13,10))),$H$12:$I$14,2,FALSE)
```

[image: Dates]

[Sheet](https://covid19.framadrop.org/lufi/r/gKAuDE2u07#a6QHIdIkB/nNhb9cXAHFddEZ6EDH4aPiGVsyCbTcgsM=)